# How can I redirect multiple URLs to a single URL for the homepage?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a site built on codeigniter but I have come accross a small issue. Basically the homepage can be accessed through 3 different urls, being:

www.domain.com/en

www.domain.com/en/

www.domain.com/en/home.html

I'd like the first and third url to redirect to the second (www.domain.com/en/).

I've been playing around with .htaccess for hours and I can't seem to get any changes done.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**Edit:**
Here is my current .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^en(/home.html)?$ /en/ [L]
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the url they typed in or does that have to be changed too?

Comment: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)` ..I don't get this one. What's the $1 doing?

Comment: The $1 is the match from the RewriteRule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^en(/home.html)?$ /en/ [L]`

This matches only /en and /en/home.html, no other urls.

Comment: This makes sense and should work but for some reason it doesn't. Whatever I try to do it seems like it has no effect. I am starting to worry that something might be conflicting in such a way that rewrites are no longer effective. I've attached my current .htaccess

Comment: @user447119: Make sure to use a proper order: In general, put rules that cause an external redirect in front of those rules that just cause an internal rewrite.

Comment: To cause an external redirect instead of an internal rewrite, you need to set the *R* flag.

Comment: Thank you Gumbo you are right, I just needed to add the R flag! Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution doesnt work because any input has allready been captured by `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]` [The `L` flag denotes last, meaning that no further rules should be processed.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Everything from here has to do with the line mentioned above
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L] # This catches all input

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^en(/home.html)?$ /en/ [L]
```

Instead, anything you want processed needs to be moved up before that line:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^en(/home.html)?$ /en/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Beyond that, reading up on [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) cant hurt here.

Comment: Changing the order of the rules didn't work I'm afraid. I've tried a variety of different possible solutions but I still can't get it to work. The other rewrite rules work fine, it's only this rule that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as changing

`^en(/home.html)?$ /en/ [L]`

to

`^/en(/home.html)?$ /en/ [L]` (notice the extra slash)